# puppeteer-sharp Can't get an element in a combo box with page.ClickAsync()

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

I am trying to use the puppeteer-sharp page.ClickAsync() method to click an element in a combo box. I need to get

this below (Canadian Dollar).

</li><li class="favorite"><div class="display">Canadian Dollar</div><div class="value">CAD</div>

<div class="container want">`your text`
<div class="label"><strong>Currency I want:</strong></div>
<div class="currency-container">
<div class="want-select collapse">                <div class="overlay">                    <div class="colorBlock active" data-color="#0000e0" style="border-top: 2px solid transparent; border-left: 2px solid transparent; border-bottom: 2px solid transparent; color: rgb(0, 0, 224);">EUR</div>                    <div class="amount" align="right"></div>                </div>                <div class="select-container">            <div class="currencyPicker" data-index="">                <input class="search" placeholder="Type to search...">                <ul class="list" style="display: none;"><li class="groupLabel favorite"><div class="display">Favorites</div><div class="value"></div></li><li class="favorite"><div class="display">Euro</div><div class="value">EUR</div></li><li class="favorite"><div class="display">US Dollar</div><div class="value">USD</div></li><li class="favorite"><div class="display">British Pound</div><div class="value">GBP</div></li><li class="favorite"><div class="display">Canadian Dollar</div><div class="value">CAD</div></li><li class="favorite"><div class="display">Australian Dollar</div><div class="value">AUD</div></li><li class="groupLabel"><div class="display">A</div><div class="value"></div></li><li><div class="display">Afghanistan Afghani</div><div class="value">AFN</div></li><li><div class="display">Afghanistan Old Afghani*</div><div class="value">AFA</div></li><li><div class="display">Albanian Lek</div><div class="value">ALL</div></li><li><div class="display">Algerian Dinar</div><div class="value">DZD</div></li><li><div class="display">Andorran Franc*</div><div class="value">ADF</div></li><li><div

I have tried many different ways, but nothing is working.

await page1.ClickAsync(".body,.controls,.secondary,.container want,.currency-container,.want-select collapse,.select-container,.currencyPicker,.list,.favorite,.dispaly,.value, CAD");

await page1.ClickAsync(".want-select,.select-container");

await page1.ClickAsync("div[class='display']:has-text('Canadian Dollar')");

I have tried.

await page1.ClickAsync(".want-select,.select-container");

await page1.ClickAsync(".body,.controls,.secondary,.container want,.currency-container,.want-select collapse,.select-container,.currencyPicker,.list,.favorite,.dispaly,.value, CAD");

await page1.ClickAsync("div[class='display']");

await page1.ClickAsync("div[class='display']:has-text('Canadian Dollar')");

Comment: I got some help from the man himself Dario Kondratiuk.

Answer (score 0):

This worked
var elements = await page1.XPathAsync("//html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li[5]/div[2]");
await elements[0].ClickAsync();

and this too.

await page1.ClickAsync("#hcc>div.body>div.controls>div.secondary>div.container.want>div.currency-container>div.want-select.collapse.active>div.select-container>div>ul>li:nth-child(5)>div.value")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).